# Powershell SQL commands through Invoke-AzVMRunCommand

Tags: sql-server, powershell, remote-server, invoke-command

I have a script that does SQL backup and restore. It works with SQL Server 2014 Standard and SQL Server 2019 Standard.

I am using either SQL Server module or the DBATools module in PowerShell.

When I execute the script locally it successfully creates the SQL credential and backs up the databases

However, from another server I have to trigger that backup remotely.

I use `Invoke-AzVmRunCommand`.

When I execute the script it successfully changes the directory to

```
SQLSERVER:\SQL\$env:COMPUTERNAME\DEFAULT
```

Then at whichever function in the script that involves SQL it just fails.

No specific error, just:

> Failed to create credentials or backup and restore databases

Answer (score 0):

In the script executed remotely, if we print the command whoami in powershell, the user running the powershell session will be NTAuthority\System.

In order to be able to execute any powershell commands related to the SQL server, login to the server, open SQL Management Studio, expand Security->Logins and provide the sysadmin role for the NTAUTHORITY\System account.